# Move the any elements preceding-sibling of <section> element and following-sibling of <section> element under the <section> element

Tags: xml, xslt

We are trying to move the any tags under the `section` elements, if tags are preceding-sibling of `section` and following-sibling of `section` elements.

Please see the example below and suggest!
Thanks in advance!

**input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book xmlns:dctm="http://www.documentum.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="D:\Work_From_Home\Metapercept\Project\AICPA\AICPA\final-set\AICPA XML baseline\AICPA XML baseline\PS-XML-June23/proflit.xsd" id="ps" role="AICPA_Professional_Standards">
    <bookinfo>
        <titleabbrev>AICPA Professional Standards</titleabbrev>
        <title>AICPA Professional Standards</title>
        <abstract>
            <para><emphasis role="italic">AICPA Professional Standards</emphasis></para>
        </abstract>
    </bookinfo>
 <chapter id="ps_applicability" role="ls_level_2">
    <chapterinfo>
        <titleabbrev>Applicability of AICPA Professional Standards</titleabbrev>
        <title role="ps_level_2">Applicability of AICPA Professional Standards</title>
    </chapterinfo>
    <section id="ps_part1" role="ls_level_4">
        <sectioninfo>
            <titleabbrev>Applicability of AICPA Professional Standards to Audits
                of Financial Statements</titleabbrev>
            <title role="ps_section_heading">Applicability of AICPA Professional
                Standards to Audits of Financial Statements</title>
        </sectioninfo>
        <section id="ps_part1_standards_applicable_to_the_audits_of_issuers" role="ls_level_5">
            <sectioninfo>
                <titleabbrev>Standards Applicable to the Audits of Entities as Defined
                    by the Act, as Amended</titleabbrev>
                <title role="ps_main_heading">Standards Applicable to the Audits of
                    Entities as Defined by the Act, as Amended</title>
            </sectioninfo>
            <para role="ps_indent_0"><olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="section_3_rule_3100">Rule 3100</olink>, <emphasis role="italic">Compliance with Auditing and Related Professional Practice
                Standards</emphasis>,<footnote id="ps_part1_fn2" label="fn 2" role="number">
                    <para>All PCAOB Rules can be found in <olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="ps-pcaob"><emphasis role="italic">PCAOB Standards and Related
                        Rules</emphasis></olink>.</para>
                </footnote> issued by the PCAOB, generally requires all registered
                public accounting firms to adhere to the PCAOB’s standards in connection
                with the preparation or issuance of any audit report on the financial
                statements of an entity as defined by the Act, as amended. <olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="section_3_rule_3100">Rule 3100</olink> requires registered public accounting firms and their associated
                persons to comply with all applicable standards. Accordingly, if the
                PCAOB's standards do not apply to an engagement or other activity
                of the firm, <olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="section_3_rule_3100">Rule 3100</olink>, by its own terms, does not apply to that engagement
                or activity.</para>
            <para role="ps_indent_0"><olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="section_3_rule_3101">Rule 3101</olink>, <emphasis role="italic">Certain Terms Used in Auditing and Related Professional
                Practice Standards</emphasis>, issued by the PCAOB, defines the degree
                of responsibility imposed on the auditor by the use of certain terms
                in the PCAOB’s auditing and related professional practice standards,
                including the interim standards adopted in <olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="section_3_rule_3200t">Rule 3200</olink>, <emphasis role="italic">Auditing Standards</emphasis>; <olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="section_3_rule_3300t">Rule 3300T</olink>, <emphasis role="italic">Interim Attestation Standards</emphasis>; <olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="section_3_rule_3400t">Rule 3400T</olink>, <emphasis role="italic">Interim Quality Control Standards</emphasis>; and <olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="section_3_rule_3500t">Rule 3500T</olink>, <emphasis role="italic">Interim Ethics and Independence
                    Standards</emphasis>.</para>
        </section>
        <section id="ps_part1_audits_of_a_nonissuers" role="ls_level_5">
            <sectioninfo>
                <titleabbrev>Audits of a Nonissuer’s Financial Statements Audited
                    in Accordance With Both GAAS and Another Set of Auditing Standards</titleabbrev>
                <title role="ps_main_heading">Audits of a Nonissuer’s Financial Statements
                    Audited in Accordance With Both GAAS and Another Set of Auditing Standards</title>
            </sectioninfo>
            <para role="ps_indent_0"><olink targetdoc="ps" targetptr="ad_700">AU-C section 700</olink>, <emphasis role="italic">Forming an Opinion
                and Reporting on Financial Statements</emphasis>, addresses the auditor’s
                report for audits conducted in accordance with both GAAS and another
                set of auditing standards. <olink targetdoc="ps" targetptr="ad_700_44">Paragraph .44</olink> of AU-C section 700 explains that the auditor
                may indicate that the audit was conducted in accordance with GAAS
                and also conducted in accordance with another set of auditing standards
                (for example, International Standards on Auditing or <emphasis role="italic">Government Auditing Standards</emphasis>). <olink targetdoc="ps" targetptr="ad_700_44">Paragraph .44</olink> also states
                that the auditor should not refer to having conducted an audit in
                accordance with another set of auditing standards in addition to GAAS,
                unless the audit was conducted in accordance with both sets of standards
                in their entirety. <olink targetdoc="ps" targetptr="ad_700_45">Paragraph
                    .45</olink> of AU-C section 700 goes on to state that when the auditor’s
                report refers to both GAAS and another set of auditing standards,
                the auditor’s report should identify the other set of auditing standards,
                as well as their origin.</para>
        </section>
        <paraBlock role="ps_box_shade"><para>For more general guidance on
            applying professional judgement and maintaining an inquiring mind
            and awareness of possible biases, a nonauthoritative Conceptual Framework
            Toolkit for Members in Public Practice is available at 
            <ulink url="https://us.aicpa.org/content/dam/aicpa/interestareas/professionalethics/resources/downloadabledocuments/toolkitsandaids/conceptual-framework-toolkit-for-members-in-public-practice-final.pdf">https://us.aicpa.org/content/dam/aicpa/interestareas/professionalethics/resources/downloadabledocuments/toolkitsandaids/conceptual-framework-toolkit-for-members-in-public-practice-final.pdf</ulink>.</para></paraBlock>
        <para role="ps_subsub_heading">Effective Date</para>
        <itemizedlist mark="bullet" role="ps_indent_2"><?Pub Dtl?>
            <listitem><?Pub Dtl?><para><?Pub Dtl?>Requiring communication of critical
                audit matters (CAMs). Any matter arising from the audit of the financial
                statements that was communicated or required to be communicated to
                the audit committee and that</para></listitem>
        </itemizedlist>
        <section id="ps_part1_audits_of_a_nov" role="ls_level_5">
            <sectioninfo>
                <titleabbrev>Audits of a Nonissuer’s Financial Statements Audited
                    in Accordance With the Standards of the PCAOB and GAAS When the Audit
                    Is Not Within the Jurisdiction of the PCAOB</titleabbrev>
                <title role="ps_main_heading">Audits of a Nonissuer’s Financial Statements
                    Audited in Accordance With the Standards of the PCAOB and GAAS When
                    the Audit Is Not Within the Jurisdiction of the PCAOB</title>
            </sectioninfo>
            <para role="ps_indent_0">When conducting an audit of financial statements
                in accordance with the standards of the PCAOB and the audit is not
                within the jurisdiction of the PCAOB, <olink targetdoc="ps" targetptr="ad_700_46">paragraph .46</olink> of AU-C section 700 states
                that the auditor is required to also conduct the audit in accordance
                with GAAS. <olink targetdoc="ps" targetptr="ad_700_46">Paragraph .46</olink> goes on to state that, in such circumstances, when the auditor refers
                to the standards of the PCAOB in addition to GAAS in the auditor’s
                report, the auditor should use the form of report required by the
                standards of the PCAOB, amended to state that the audit was also conducted
                in accordance with GAAS.</para>
        </section>
        <section id="ps_part1_integrated_audit_of_a" role="ls_level_5">
            <sectioninfo>
                <titleabbrev>Integrated Audit of a Nonissuer’s Financial Statements</titleabbrev>
                <title role="ps_main_heading">Integrated Audit of a Nonissuer’s Financial
                    Statements</title>
            </sectioninfo>
            <para role="ps_indent_0"><olink targetptr="ad_940">AU-C section 940</olink>, <emphasis role="italic">An Audit of Internal Control Over Financial
                Reporting That Is Integrated With an Audit of Financial Statements</emphasis>, establishes requirements and provides guidance that applies only
                when an auditor is engaged to perform an audit of internal control
                over financial reporting that is integrated with an audit of financial
                statements (<emphasis role="italic">integrated audit</emphasis>).</para>
        </section>
    </section>
</chapter>
</book>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book xmlns:dctm="http://www.documentum.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="D:\Work_From_Home\Metapercept\Project\AICPA\AICPA\final-set\AICPA XML baseline\AICPA XML baseline\PS-XML-June23/proflit.xsd" id="ps" role="AICPA_Professional_Standards">
    <bookinfo>
        <titleabbrev>AICPA Professional Standards</titleabbrev>
        <title>AICPA Professional Standards</title>
        <abstract>
            <para><emphasis role="italic">AICPA Professional Standards</emphasis></para>
        </abstract>
    </bookinfo>
 <chapter id="ps_applicability" role="ls_level_2">
    <chapterinfo>
        <titleabbrev>Applicability of AICPA Professional Standards</titleabbrev>
        <title role="ps_level_2">Applicability of AICPA Professional Standards</title>
    </chapterinfo>
    <section id="ps_part1" role="ls_level_4">
        <sectioninfo>
            <titleabbrev>Applicability of AICPA Professional Standards to Audits
                of Financial Statements</titleabbrev>
            <title role="ps_section_heading">Applicability of AICPA Professional
                Standards to Audits of Financial Statements</title>
        </sectioninfo>
        <section id="ps_part1_standards_applicable_to_the_audits_of_issuers" role="ls_level_5">
            <sectioninfo>
                <titleabbrev>Standards Applicable to the Audits of Entities as Defined
                    by the Act, as Amended</titleabbrev>
                <title role="ps_main_heading">Standards Applicable to the Audits of
                    Entities as Defined by the Act, as Amended</title>
            </sectioninfo>
            <para role="ps_indent_0"><olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="section_3_rule_3100">Rule 3100</olink>, <emphasis role="italic">Compliance with Auditing and Related Professional Practice
                Standards</emphasis>,<footnote id="ps_part1_fn2" label="fn 2" role="number">
                    <para>All PCAOB Rules can be found in <olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="ps-pcaob"><emphasis role="italic">PCAOB Standards and Related
                        Rules</emphasis></olink>.</para>
                </footnote> issued by the PCAOB, generally requires all registered
                public accounting firms to adhere to the PCAOB’s standards in connection
                with the preparation or issuance of any audit report on the financial
                statements of an entity as defined by the Act, as amended. <olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="section_3_rule_3100">Rule 3100</olink> requires registered public accounting firms and their associated
                persons to comply with all applicable standards. Accordingly, if the
                PCAOB's standards do not apply to an engagement or other activity
                of the firm, <olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="section_3_rule_3100">Rule 3100</olink>, by its own terms, does not apply to that engagement
                or activity.</para>
            <para role="ps_indent_0"><olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="section_3_rule_3101">Rule 3101</olink>, <emphasis role="italic">Certain Terms Used in Auditing and Related Professional
                Practice Standards</emphasis>, issued by the PCAOB, defines the degree
                of responsibility imposed on the auditor by the use of certain terms
                in the PCAOB’s auditing and related professional practice standards,
                including the interim standards adopted in <olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="section_3_rule_3200t">Rule 3200</olink>, <emphasis role="italic">Auditing Standards</emphasis>; <olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="section_3_rule_3300t">Rule 3300T</olink>, <emphasis role="italic">Interim Attestation Standards</emphasis>; <olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="section_3_rule_3400t">Rule 3400T</olink>, <emphasis role="italic">Interim Quality Control Standards</emphasis>; and <olink targetdoc="ps-pcaob" targetptr="section_3_rule_3500t">Rule 3500T</olink>, <emphasis role="italic">Interim Ethics and Independence
                    Standards</emphasis>.</para>
        </section>
        <section id="ps_part1_audits_of_a_nonissuers" role="ls_level_5">
            <sectioninfo>
                <titleabbrev>Audits of a Nonissuer’s Financial Statements Audited
                    in Accordance With Both GAAS and Another Set of Auditing Standards</titleabbrev>
                <title role="ps_main_heading">Audits of a Nonissuer’s Financial Statements
                    Audited in Accordance With Both GAAS and Another Set of Auditing Standards</title>
            </sectioninfo>
            <para role="ps_indent_0"><olink targetdoc="ps" targetptr="ad_700">AU-C section 700</olink>, <emphasis role="italic">Forming an Opinion
                and Reporting on Financial Statements</emphasis>, addresses the auditor’s
                report for audits conducted in accordance with both GAAS and another
                set of auditing standards. <olink targetdoc="ps" targetptr="ad_700_44">Paragraph .44</olink> of AU-C section 700 explains that the auditor
                may indicate that the audit was conducted in accordance with GAAS
                and also conducted in accordance with another set of auditing standards
                (for example, International Standards on Auditing or <emphasis role="italic">Government Auditing Standards</emphasis>). <olink targetdoc="ps" targetptr="ad_700_44">Paragraph .44</olink> also states
                that the auditor should not refer to having conducted an audit in
                accordance with another set of auditing standards in addition to GAAS,
                unless the audit was conducted in accordance with both sets of standards
                in their entirety. <olink targetdoc="ps" targetptr="ad_700_45">Paragraph
                    .45</olink> of AU-C section 700 goes on to state that when the auditor’s
                report refers to both GAAS and another set of auditing standards,
                the auditor’s report should identify the other set of auditing standards,
                as well as their origin.</para>
            <paraBlock role="ps_box_shade"><para>For more general guidance on
                applying professional judgement and maintaining an inquiring mind
                and awareness of possible biases, a nonauthoritative Conceptual Framework
                Toolkit for Members in Public Practice is available at 
                <ulink url="https://us.aicpa.org/content/dam/aicpa/interestareas/professionalethics/resources/downloadabledocuments/toolkitsandaids/conceptual-framework-toolkit-for-members-in-public-practice-final.pdf">https://us.aicpa.org/content/dam/aicpa/interestareas/professionalethics/resources/downloadabledocuments/toolkitsandaids/conceptual-framework-toolkit-for-members-in-public-practice-final.pdf</ulink>.</para></paraBlock>
            <para role="ps_subsub_heading">Effective Date</para>
            <itemizedlist mark="bullet" role="ps_indent_2"><?Pub Dtl?>
                <listitem><?Pub Dtl?><para><?Pub Dtl?>Requiring communication of critical
                    audit matters (CAMs). Any matter arising from the audit of the financial
                    statements that was communicated or required to be communicated to
                    the audit committee and that</para></listitem>
            </itemizedlist>
        </section>


        
        
        <section id="ps_part1_audits_of_a_nov" role="ls_level_5">
            <sectioninfo>
                <titleabbrev>Audits of a Nonissuer’s Financial Statements Audited
                    in Accordance With the Standards of the PCAOB and GAAS When the Audit
                    Is Not Within the Jurisdiction of the PCAOB</titleabbrev>
                <title role="ps_main_heading">Audits of a Nonissuer’s Financial Statements
                    Audited in Accordance With the Standards of the PCAOB and GAAS When
                    the Audit Is Not Within the Jurisdiction of the PCAOB</title>
            </sectioninfo>
            <para role="ps_indent_0">When conducting an audit of financial statements
                in accordance with the standards of the PCAOB and the audit is not
                within the jurisdiction of the PCAOB, <olink targetdoc="ps" targetptr="ad_700_46">paragraph .46</olink> of AU-C section 700 states
                that the auditor is required to also conduct the audit in accordance
                with GAAS. <olink targetdoc="ps" targetptr="ad_700_46">Paragraph .46</olink> goes on to state that, in such circumstances, when the auditor refers
                to the standards of the PCAOB in addition to GAAS in the auditor’s
                report, the auditor should use the form of report required by the
                standards of the PCAOB, amended to state that the audit was also conducted
                in accordance with GAAS.</para>
        </section>
        <section id="ps_part1_integrated_audit_of_a" role="ls_level_5">
            <sectioninfo>
                <titleabbrev>Integrated Audit of a Nonissuer’s Financial Statements</titleabbrev>
                <title role="ps_main_heading">Integrated Audit of a Nonissuer’s Financial
                    Statements</title>
            </sectioninfo>
            <para role="ps_indent_0"><olink targetptr="ad_940">AU-C section 940</olink>, <emphasis role="italic">An Audit of Internal Control Over Financial
                Reporting That Is Integrated With an Audit of Financial Statements</emphasis>, establishes requirements and provides guidance that applies only
                when an auditor is engaged to perform an audit of internal control
                over financial reporting that is integrated with an audit of financial
                statements (<emphasis role="italic">integrated audit</emphasis>).</para>
        </section>
    </section>
</chapter>
</book>
```

**My XSLT code:**

```
<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::para[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='section']]">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][local-name()='para'][1]" mode="subhead-ps"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This seems to be a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info)  problem. Which version of XSLT does your processor support?

Comment: I am using xslt 2.0

Comment: Please help, unable to get the result

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Answer (score 1):

Try perhaps something like:

```
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="section">
        <section>
            <xsl:copy-of select="* | current-group()[position() > 1]" />
        </section>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
```

This needs to be called from the context of the parent element of `section` (which your example does not show).

Comment: Thanks michael.hor257k, Please see the above input of the query

Comment: Please suggest the xsl code on the above input

Comment: @KitaAnsari This is my suggestion. It should work as I said. Also please make up your mind who you are; it's confusing when you use 2 different usernames.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes, By mistake created two users, sorry for that, Yes it is working for 1st input, if you see I have shared the another input, it is not working for that

Comment: I apologized for that confusion, Please look the 2nd input and try to suggest the xsl code on that

Comment: @Kitabuddin I repeat: that is my suggestion for your 2nd input as well (which should be added to your question and not posted as an answer). If it's "not working" then you need to show exactly what you did and also what is the expected result. That's what [mcve] means.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Please see in the input, I have edited the input and added the whole structure input, what I am working and what I want to output, Please look and sorry for that If I have disturb you

Comment: See this below XSLT fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94humrx

Comment: @DanielHaley, Please look my input and expected output

Comment: Guys, It is Humble request, Please look again on my question, I unable to get the result

Answer (score 1):

A different option, instead of using xsl:for-each-group and group-starting-with, is to use an xsl:key to associate the following-sibling elements with their preceding-sibling `section`'s...

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:key name="orphan_sect_siblings" 
        match="*[not(self::section)][preceding-sibling::section]" 
        use="preceding-sibling::section[1]/generate-id()"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="section[following-sibling::*[1][not(self::section)]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('orphan_sect_siblings',generate-id())" mode="keep"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[not(self::section)][preceding-sibling::section]"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVQdov/2

Comment: please look this link: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFD9uuz if you see in this link input has 1st section output is not coming correctly, it is dropping the 'section' element and keep the child of section elements

Comment: Still, I am struggling on this question, please help me guys

Comment: @Kitabuddin - Updated my answer with a completely different approach.

Comment: Thank you so much, It is working fine, I appreciate you

Comment: @Kitabuddin - please consider accepting this answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.